# ViewControllers Array index of TabBarController return NSRangeException

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have 5 items on tabBarController and  I control on didSelect tabBar (with index 1 and index 3) only.  When I click on item with index 3 the ViewController show successfully , but when I click on item with index 1 I receive this error:
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'`

This is code on didSelect tabBar:

```
if item.tag == 1 {

         self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        let chatListController = ChatListViewController.viewControllerFromStoryborad(storyName: "Chat", viewName: "ChatList")

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let navigation = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Chat_Navigation") as! UINavigationController

        navigation.pushViewController(chatListController, animated: true)
            self.viewControllers?[1] = navigation
            self.selectedIndex = 1
    }


    if item.tag == 3 {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
            let manageController = ManagingNormalViewController.viewControllerFromStoryborad(storyName: "Order", viewName: "Manage_Normal")

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let navigation = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OrderNavigation") as! UINavigationController

            navigation.pushViewController(manageController, animated: true)
            self.viewControllers?[3] = navigation
            self.selectedIndex = 3

        }
```

Why I receive this error ?! the code is same and index of array is right.
This is image of my TabBarController :
[image]

Comment: Why are you using tags?

Comment: `override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem)`  Delegate

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: `self.viewControllers?[1] = navigation` give me NSRangeException , however  `self.viewControllers?[3] = navigation` give me successful